# How do I multiply two separate table values or posted data with a MYSQL value to store?

Tags: php, mysql

I feel like this should be really simple and I understand the basics of how multiplying figures in MYSQL as well as PHP works but for some reason no matter what route I try I haven't had any luck even after checking forums and videos.

I want this to be executed to store the end result in MYSQL so I do not need to echo the result as many tutorials show.. The one variable I'm needing to select is in one database table and the other variable is in another table.. I'm also posting one of the variables that is needed to be multiplied prior to the result being executed so if it is easier to multiply the posted variable with the one already in the database rather than after it's been updated into the other database table that works too but I haven't had any luck with either.

Any help would be very much appreciated!! 
I apologize in advance if this question was already answered or if it's super simple, after nothing working for three days I figured I'd try asking on here.

I'm thinking the end result should look something like this..

```
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

include('session.php');

$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$item = $_POST['item'];

$sql2 = "SELECT Price FROM items WHERE item='$item'";
$res = mysql_query($sql2);
$sql = "UPDATE ordered_items SET oi_total = ('$res' * '$quantity') WHERE oi_name='$item' AND oi_employee='$login_session'";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    header('Refresh: 4; URL=http://websitehere.com');
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Cloud you please show in code what do you need? I couldn't understand your explanations.

Comment: `wanting` in second paragraph etymologically means `lacking`. Choose your words wisely! :)

Comment: Could you state an example of what you want as the final result?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the new information instead of using the comments.

Comment: Thank you all for your input so far! I added an example of what I'm thinking it should look like and changed my wording in the second paragraph!